# Proof that any rational can be bound by two powers of another rational

Tags: analysis, exponentiation, rational-numbers

Let $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}, \epsilon>0$ and $a\in\mathbb {Q}, a>1$, prove that exists $n_1,n_2 \in\mathbb {N} $ such that
$$a^{-n_2}<\epsilon <a^{n_1}$$.

I saw someone using euclid's division somewhere to prove this but I'm completely lost...

note: You are only allowed to use rationals, therefore things valid for real numbers like limits can't be used.

Comment: $a^{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$ and $a^{-n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$, so... (nothing special about rationals here).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add, I can't use things of real numbers, only rationals can be used (since I'm on rationals there isn't such a thing as limits). I'll edit the question

Comment: Can you use the fact that the equation $a^x = \epsilon$ has a unique solution $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ for any $a, e \gt 0$?

Comment: @dxiv nope, real numbers weren't defined yet. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\varepsilon=1$, then it's obvious that $a^{-1}<\varepsilon<a$.

Suppose $\varepsilon>1$. Set $a=1+t$; by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) (which just requires an easy induction)
$$
a^n=(1+t)^n>1+nt=1+n(a-1)
$$
for $n>0$, so you just need to find $n_1$ such that
$$
\varepsilon<1+n_1(a-1)
$$
and this means
$$
n>\frac{\varepsilon-1}{a-1}
$$
which is surely possible. Can you find $n_2$?

If $0<\varepsilon<1$< then $\varepsilon^{-1}>1$ and you can use the previous case.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't understand the $n_2$ part. $a $ might be lower than $\epsilon $.

Comment: @Matheusbarroscastro OK, that's taken care by a similar argument.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thank you so much!